# systrace.py not found Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, systrace

I'm currently trying to run the systrace tool for analysing my ui performance. I setup my environment as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/systrace.html#syntax

But when I try to run

```
python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html gfx
```

in the Android Studio terminal I get the following error:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'systrace.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I did not find a working solution yet.

Comment: The error message says `systrace.py` was not found. Are your running this command from the right path (maybe in `android-sdk/tools/systrace`) ?

Comment: Yes I run the command in that path

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the project has been moved or rewritten, but the `systrace` is now part of the [catapult project](https://chromium.googlesource.com/catapult);

Answer (score -2):

go to the Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/systrace

```
cd /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/systrace
```

and run

```
python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html gfx
```